# How to find executions of a particular job?

Tags: circleci

In our project, we have a `release-workflow` workflow executing every time our `master` branch is updated, which includes an optional manually-triggered job called `Production Deployment`.

Now, the problem I have is that in order to see when was the last deployment of a specific microservice, I need to expand all workflows in CircleCI and search where the `Production Deployment` job was triggered and succeeded (green icon).

Is there a way to see all executions of `Production Deployment` job in one page? So, on this page, I'll see when was the last time this job was triggered/succeeded.

I guess, in theory, it would be something like **/{project}/jobs/production_deployment**

The only thing I was able to find is [Job Legacy View](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047731771-How-To-View-All-Jobs-for-a-Project), but it shows you all jobs in a project, instead of specific one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that type of filtering in the UI (not to my knowledge). But the API is your friend.

You can use the ["Recent Builds For A Single Project" CircleCI API v1 endpoint](https://circleci.com/docs/api/v1/index.html#recent-builds-for-a-single-project), combined with [some `jq` magic](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). For example:

```
curl https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/:vcs-type/:org-name/:project?filter=successful -H "Circle-Token: <circle-token>" | jq '.[]|select (.workflows.job_name == "Production Deployment")|.build_url'
```